# import ._ or import.{ classOne, classTwo}

Tags: scala

will chossing what classes I want from package will speed up compiling process ?
If for example in package me.test I have 50 classess, and I just need two of them and I will do :

```
 import me.test.{ classOne, classTwo}
```

instead of

```
 import me.test._
```

?
Thanks

Comment: Removing `[java]` as you don't appear to want the answer about Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is wildcard import bad in Scala with respect to incremental compilation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291772/is-wildcard-import-bad-in-scala-with-respect-to-incremental-compilation)

Answer (score 9):

While the performance impact is negligible, here are a few things that happen:

- Code size grows, number of classes in a package will grow.
- You won't know where `Foo` comes from. This if very often a problem. Eclipse is slow with really large projects.
- `Open declaration` is only available for files fetched in the
  `EclipseKeys.withSource` phase of the SBT plugin. A lot of libraries DON'T have it.

A few things from the [**Twitter Scala Style Guideline**](http://twitter.github.io/effectivescala/#Formatting-Imports) that have come very handy in practice:

- Sort imports alphabetically, they are a lot easier to follow visually.
- Only use a wildcard `import pkg._` for more than 6 classes imported.
- Use the `import pck.{ Class1, Obj1 }` layout for up to 6 classes.
- Use multi-row imports for clarity

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it will make a significant difference for compilation speed.

In my opinion you should base that decision on what you want to communicate with that import.

- Do you want to use the whole package? Use `import me.test._`.
- Do you want to cherry-pick only some parts of the package? Use `import me.test.{ ClassOne, classTwo }`.